# Is there a command line equivalent to "Dev Containers: Rebuild and Reopen in Container"?

Tags: command-line, vscode-devcontainer

I was hoping to automate as much of the "environment setup" as possible for myself and my team through a shell script or something in our .bashrc file. A blocker for that has been the "set up our container in VSCode" step. Right now we open up VSCode and `F1` then select `Dev Containers: Rebuild and Reopen in Container`.

Is there a unix/linux command line equivalent to do the `F1` + `Dev Containers: Rebuild and Reopen in Container`?

We're using a devcontainer.json right now that looks something like:

```
{
    "image": //predefined image getting pulled from a repository
    "initializationCommand": //create mounting dirs if they don't exist already
    "remoteUser": //name
    "containerUser": //name
    "workspaceMount": // file path to mount
    "mounts": [//all our mounts
              ]
    "remoteEnv" : { //path 
    }
    "customizations": {
        "vscode: { "extensions": [ // list of extensions
                 ]}
}
```

I tried googling around and reading some of the VSCode documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers). But might have missed something saying it could or could not be done.